How to modify rust types passed to python which were initially created in python from Pyo3
I've created the following directory structure
- python
 * main.py
- src
 * lib.rs
* Cargo.toml
* pyproject.toml

where only lib.rs and main.py are custom made, the rest was generated by maturin init
lib.rs is :
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Float3{
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    x : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    y : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    z : f64,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Float3 {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(x : f64, y : f64, z : f64) -> Self {
        Float3 { x, y, z}
    }
}

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ParentFloat3 {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    data: Vec<Float3>,
}
#[pymethods]
impl ParentFloat3 {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(data : Vec<Float3>) -> Self {
        ParentFloat3 {data}
    }
}

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ParentFunctions {
     python_functions :Vec<PyObject>
}

#[pymethods]
impl ParentFunctions {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(python_functions : Vec<PyObject>) -> Self {
        ParentFunctions {python_functions }
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn test_fn<'py>(parent_float3 : &Bound<'_, ParentFloat3>, parent_functions : &Bound<'_, ParentFunctions>) -> PyResult<i32>{
    // let parent_casted : &Bound<'_, ParentFloat3>  =  parent.downcast()?;
    // let parent_borrowed = parent.borrow_mut(); 
    for python_function in parent_functions.borrow().python_functions.iter(){
        python_function.call1(parent_float3.py(), (parent_float3.borrow_mut(),))?;
    }

    Ok(10)
}
/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn test_pyo3(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Float3>()?; 
    m.add_class::<ParentFloat3>()?; 
    m.add_class::<ParentFunctions>()?; 
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(test_fn, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

And main.py is:
import test_pyo3


def modify_parent_float_3(parent : test_pyo3.ParentFloat3):
    for value in parent.data:
        value.x += 1.0
    parent.data[0].x += 1.0
    pass

def main():
    temp_float3s = test_pyo3.ParentFloat3([test_pyo3.Float3(0,0,0)])
    temp_functions = test_pyo3.ParentFunctions([
         modify_parent_float_3
    ])

    print(temp_float3s.data[0].x, temp_float3s.data[0].y, temp_float3s.data[0].z)
    test_pyo3.test_fn(temp_float3s, temp_functions)
    print(temp_float3s.data[0].x, temp_float3s.data[0].y, temp_float3s.data[0].z)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

out put is:
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0

I'm trying to modify parent.data but nothing done to elements of data actually changes what is inside. Modifying a raw test_pyo3.Float3(...) seems to work, but not a Vec of them.
Note data must be a fast contiguous set of data, determined from the rust side and this can't be a PyList or numpy array, or an array of PyRef or similar objects. It also may not be a Vec in the future (for example, may be a nalgebra type).  So converting to some python native type is not an option here.
How do I get changes properly propagated to temp_float3s?

It works with the Float3 object because here you have a setter for the actual element.
But what happens with your getter for parent.data is that it returns a new list (check the type. It won't be a Rusty class, it will be a plain python list). That's because of the automatic conversion of (some) Rust types to python objects and vice versa.
You have a setter for parent.data, but that just lets you replace data with a new list of Float3s. In the current code you're most definitely not getting a mutable reference to your data vector.
What to do? Write some custom methods for the parent class so you can modify it in a way that makes sense for your actual needs. That method would take a &mut self and thereby let you modify the vector on the rust side of things.
I find generally that rust extensions work best if you dont' have too much uncontrolled back and forth across the language boundary.

Would overriding get/set item/ iterator protocol methods work here then?  Our needs are basically arbitrarily modifying arrays of nalgebra and primitive types from python, there's not another option because this whole system is designed to allow people who don't know rust to prototype arbitrary things for our system in python, so we don't know how they'll use these values before hand.   My only concern is how to avoid getting a copy only type from the iterator and get methods?

Things can get quite messy then. I have not too much experience with that. If you "hide" everything behind method calls, it should work, and then you can see which of the protocol methods you can implement how for better quality of life.
